# SET и SELECT в одном запросе (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли присвоить переменную и выполнить **SELECT** не разбивая запрос на подзапросы?

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '', [
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
]);

$statement = $pdo->prepare("
    SET @PREV_STATE = @@GLOBAL.innodb_stats_on_metadata;            
    SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;
    SELECT 
        kcu.`TABLE_NAME` AS dstTable,
        kcu.`COLUMN_NAME` AS dstColumn
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
    WHERE kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = :schemaName
        AND kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = :tableName
        AND kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = :columnName;
    SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=@PREV_STATE;
");
$statement->execute([
    ':schemaName' => 'test',
    ':tableName' => 'user',
    ':columnName' => 'user_id',
]);

print_r($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Такой код падает c `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`

Comment: Легко. Оформи инициализацию как псевдотаблицу: `... FROM (table set), (SELECT @var:=value, @var:=value, ...) WHERE ...`

Comment: Звучит неплохо. Если можно полный пример реализации в виде ответа)

Comment: Я с телефона... полный пример - убицццо. Может, кто другой сподобится.